# "Killed" running scheduler in Python

Tags: python, ubuntu, scheduler, digital-ocean

I have a scheduled job running as so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import datetime, schedule, time

from messager.send_texts import send_text
from messager.send_emails import send_email
from data.tasks import TASKS, TEXT_PREMESSAGE

DAYS = ['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday']

LUNCH_TIMES = ['17:00'] # 12pm
NIGHT_TIMES = ['02:00'] # 9pm


def get_tasks_text_message():
    return TEXT_PREMESSAGE + "\n\n" + TASKS

def schedule_reminders(days, times, schedule_package):
    for day in days:
        for time in times:
            getattr(schedule.every(), day).at(time).do(send_email, subject="Do your tasks!", body=TASKS).tag('tasks')
            getattr(schedule.every(), day).at(time).do(
                send_text,
                body=get_tasks_text_message(),
                target_phone_number='+15127365653'
            ).tag('tasks')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # M-Th at lunch
    schedule_reminders(DAYS[0:4], LUNCH_TIMES, schedule)

    # M/W when I'm home from gym
    schedule_reminders(DAYS[1:2], NIGHT_TIMES, schedule) # tuesday 2am is monday 9pm
    schedule_reminders(DAYS[3:4], NIGHT_TIMES, schedule) # thursday 2am is wednesday 9pm

    # Sa when I'm home from gym
    schedule_reminders(DAYS[5:6], ['22:30'], schedule)

    # Su when I'm home reading
    schedule_reminders(DAYS[6:7], ['17:00'], schedule)

    while True:
        """ Prove how to clear the schedule...
        https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#clear-job-by-tag
        """
        # you can clear tasks if you give them a tag using .tag('tag-name')...
        # schedule.clear('tasks')
        # schedule.clear('id_23')

        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        print(now)
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(60)
```

Code is at https://bitbucket.org/codyc54321/virtual_assistant

When I run it, it works once, then dies saying only "Killed". I get no further info

I see `/var/log/kern.log`:

```
Jul  4 05:32:38 virtual-assistant kernel: [    7.681842] xor: automatically using best checksumming function:
Jul  4 05:32:38 virtual-assistant kernel: [    7.724039]    avx       :  8469.000 MB/sec
Jul  4 05:32:38 virtual-assistant kernel: [    7.730950] async_tx: api initialized (async)
Jul  4 05:32:38 virtual-assistant kernel: [    7.764063] md: raid6 personality registered for level 6
Jul  4 05:32:38 virtual-assistant kernel: [    7.766609] md: raid5 personality registered for level 5
Jul  4 05:32:38 virtual-assistant kernel: [    7.768985] md: raid4 personality registered for level 4
Jul  4 05:32:38 virtual-assistant kernel: [    7.785045] md: raid10 personality registered for level 10
Jul  4 05:32:38 virtual-assistant kernel: [    7.866145] Btrfs loaded
Jul  4 05:32:38 virtual-assistant kernel: [    7.906183] EXT4-fs (vda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
Jul  4 05:32:38 virtual-assistant kernel: [    8.366340] Loading iSCSI transport class v2.0-870.
Jul  4 05:32:38 virtual-assistant kernel: [    8.422214] EXT4-fs (vda1): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
Jul  4 05:32:38 virtual-assistant kernel: [    8.464942] iscsi: registered transport (tcp)
Jul  4 05:32:38 virtual-assistant kernel: [    9.051867] iscsi: registered transport (iser)
Jul  4 05:32:38 virtual-assistant kernel: [   12.303381] audit: type=1400 audit(1499146352.764:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="lxc-container-default" pid=769 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jul  4 05:32:38 virtual-assistant kernel: [   12.304812] audit: type=1400 audit(1499146352.768:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="lxc-container-default-cgns" pid=769 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jul  4 05:32:38 virtual-assistant kernel: [   12.312284] audit: type=1400 audit(1499146352.776:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="lxc-container-default-with-mounting" pid=769 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jul  4 05:32:38 virtual-assistant kernel: [   12.314252] audit: type=1400 audit(1499146352.776:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="lxc-container-default-with-nesting" pid=769 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jul  4 05:32:38 virtual-assistant kernel: [   13.331096] audit: type=1400 audit(1499146353.792:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=809 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jul  4 05:32:38 virtual-assistant kernel: [   13.333858] audit: type=1400 audit(1499146353.796:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=809 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jul  4 05:32:38 virtual-assistant kernel: [   13.336588] audit: type=1400 audit(1499146353.800:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper" pid=809 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jul  4 05:32:38 virtual-assistant kernel: [   13.337167] audit: type=1400 audit(1499146353.800:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=809 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jul  4 05:32:38 virtual-assistant kernel: [   13.378712] audit: type=1400 audit(1499146353.840:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/lxc-start" pid=874 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jul  4 05:32:38 virtual-assistant kernel: [   13.505436] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
Jul  4 05:32:38 virtual-assistant kernel: [   13.653885] virtio_net virtio0 eth0: renamed from ens3
Jul  4 05:32:38 virtual-assistant kernel: [   13.731609] audit: type=1400 audit(1499146354.192:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/lxd/lxd-bridge-proxy" pid=879 comm="apparmor_parser"
Jul  4 05:32:38 virtual-assistant kernel: [   16.761538] EXT4-fs (vda1): resizing filesystem from 576000 to 5242619 blocks
Jul  4 05:32:38 virtual-assistant kernel: [   16.778647] EXT4-fs (vda1): resized filesystem to 5242619
Jul  4 05:32:38 virtual-assistant kernel: [   17.549292] cgroup: new mount options do not match the existing superblock, will be ignored
Jul  4 05:32:48 virtual-assistant kernel: [   27.862032] random: nonblocking pool is initialized
```

This app works locally, I just got a text and email. I just moved my `client_secret.json` to server and that didn't fix it either.

```
root@virtual-assistant:~# grep -E -in 'oom|kill' /var/log/*
grep: /var/log/apt: Is a directory
grep: /var/log/dist-upgrade: Is a directory
grep: /var/log/fsck: Is a directory
grep: /var/log/lxd: Is a directory
/var/log/syslog:543:Jul  4 05:32:38 virtual-assistant systemd[1]: Listening on Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status /dev/rfkill Watch.
grep: /var/log/unattended-upgrades: Is a directory
```

How can I figure this out by writing to log, when I only get 1 word of feedback? Another user said APS had error messages exactly as bad ("Killed").

Comment: You could be overflowing the available memory / swap space. Have you looked in /var/log/kern.log ?

Comment: In case there is something in another log file, you might try `$ grep -E -in 'oom|kill' /var/log/*`

Comment: Can you reduce your code to a [mcve]?